# How processor detects that an exception has occurred?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, processor

How the processor detects that an exception is occurred? Where is the checkpoint for this? Does processor goes and checks after each F-D-E cycle for exception check or something similar? If it is processor specific, how it happens in arm? 
Example: When we assert the IRQ or FIQ line, when system will go and check that line?

Comment: Everything is built-in hardware; read an ARM [*technical reference manual*](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0210c/DDI0210B.pdf), esp sec 2.8, on interrupt handling.

Answer (score 1):

Every processor will have flag registers(also known as status register) at the hardware level to represent exceptions. The bits in the registers will be hardwired so as to notify an exception. The next instructions will be executed based on these registers.

Comment: But when cpu will go and check the status register? Will it go after each cycle and check for the exception? If it is the case, I am not able to see any exception check in the 13-cycles of the arm. You can check this figure for reference http://i.stack.imgur.com/9dQt4.png

Comment: AFAIK the exception handling will be hardwired on the processor itself, so don't think you can look for instruction cycle that checks for exceptions for before starting the next instruction. I read this in a x86 book by Hall. This should be no different for ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there isn't any checkpoint. An exception signal can be triggered at any stage of the pipeline. As a couple of examples, a division by zero on execute stage, an unknown instruction at decode stage, etc... Whenever these exceptions occur, the pipeline is flushed, and the program counter (PC) is updated with the address of the corresponding vector table entry. The bottom line is that the processor doesn't periodically check if there is an exception or not. When an exception is signalled it handles it instantly.

Comment: Thanks blacklung! But when the processor will go and check that exception signal?

Comment: It doesn't check for the signal periodically. When the exception signal is asserted, this process is triggered on the next clock cycle. So a very simple timeline (probably a bit unrealistic, but still a good model) would be like C0 (Clock cycle 0): exception signal asserted, C1: flush pipeline, C2: set PC to vector table entry address and continue executing from that point